# XSLT 2.0 Xpath error "not a node item"

Tags: xslt, key, xslt-2.0

my first post here - sure hope someone will know the answer!
I have been able to find solutions for many issues I had, but not for this one.
The questions and answers on this site on the same subject did not solve my issue...

I have an xml containing Format specifications like

```
<Format>
    <TagNr>92</TagNr>
    <Option>A</Option>
    <Format>//[N]15d</Format>
</Format>
<Format>
    <TagNr>92</TagNr>
    <Option>B</Option>
    <Format>//3!a/3!a/15d</Format>
</Format>
```

TagNr + option is a unique combination within this nodeset.

I defined a key to make using the set of formats easier:

```
<xsl:key name="xx" match="//Format/Format" use="concat(../TagNr, ../Option)"/>
```

I can indeed use this key and get the correct value, but only in non-special elements; I get an error "Error in XPath 2.0 expression Not a node item" when using this key within for-each or other constructs like the one below.

What I try to achieve is the following: In other nodes processed there is a string of options for which I wish to retrieve the format for each character.
For example:

```
<Tag>
    <TagNr>92</TagNr>
    <Options>AB</Options>
</Tag>
```

I have been trying lots of variants of the below but no luck:

```
<xsl:variable name="TN"><xsl:value-of select="TagNr"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="optList">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="./Options" regex="[A-Z]">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:variable name="TNO" select="concat($TN, .)"/>
            <opt>
                <tag><xsl:value-of select="$TNO"/></tag>
                <fmt><xsl:value-of select="key('xx', $TNO)"/></fmt>
            </opt>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:variable>
```

Splitting into individual characters using the regex goes fine and when retrieving (only) the value for opt/tag that goes fine too.
But when I add opt/fmt, I run into the mentioned error message for the Xpath expression **select="key('xx', $TNO)"**.

I tried defining a variable based on the key function as suggested in another thread on this site, but did not succeed.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key() function (with two arguments) searches the document containing the context node. If the context item is not a node - for example, within analyze-string - then you will get this error, because it doesn't know which document to search. The answer is to use the third argument of key() to supply this information.

Comment: Super guys - really appreciate all your help. I wonder how exactly one specifies the third argument of the key function - will that be something like "/" to denote the document root? I can't find information on this in the XSLT 2.0 guide.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the context changes in your `analyze-string` element. Maybe the following solution will help you.

For an XML file like that :

```
<a>
    <Format>
        <TagNr>92</TagNr>
        <Option>A</Option>
        <Format>//[N]15d</Format>
    </Format>
    <Format>
        <TagNr>92</TagNr>
        <Option>B</Option>
        <Format>//3!a/3!a/15d</Format>
    </Format>
    <Tag>
        <TagNr>92</TagNr>
        <Options>AB</Options>
    </Tag>
</a>
```

Consider the following XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="xx" match="//Format/Format" use="concat(../TagNr, ../Option)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//Tag"/>            
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Tag">
        <xsl:call-template name="createOPT">
            <xsl:with-param name="str" as="xs:string" select="Options"/>
        </xsl:call-template>                
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="createOPT">
        <xsl:param name="str"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($str) > 0">
            <xsl:variable name="firstChar" select="substring($str,1,1)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="TNO" select="concat(TagNr,$firstChar)"/>
            <opt>
                <tag><xsl:value-of select="$TNO"/></tag>
                <fmt><xsl:value-of select="key('xx', $TNO)"/></fmt>
            </opt>
            <xsl:call-template name="createOPT">
                <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring($str,2)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   <opt>
      <tag>92A</tag>
      <fmt>//[N]15d</fmt>
   </opt>
   <opt>
      <tag>92B</tag>
      <fmt>//3!a/3!a/15d</fmt>
   </opt>
</result>
```

Comment: Thanks - this definitely gets me going again! And also supplies me with a means of substringing char by char which I originally wished to do. One question though: context is lost but why? And why is there no more elegant solution as mentioned in another thread on this site: define variable to regain context?

Comment: You can also work with a variable to regain context. Maybe it's more elegant. My humble personal view is that `analyze-string` is a bit akward to use and maintain, I prefer to avoid it when it's possible.

Comment: The context is not lost, however inside the analyze-string it is not a node but rather an atomic item, namely the (sub)string that is currently being processed.

Comment: Thanks Martin for pointing this. I meant the former context. I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest XSLT 2.0 way to process a string character by character is the following**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="string-to-codepoints($vStr)">
 <xsl:variable name="$vChar" select=
     "codepoints-to-string(.)"/>

 <!-- Process $vChar here: -->
</xsl:for-each/>
```

You can combine this with saving the original document context into a variable (say `$vDoc`) and using this variable as the 3rd argument of the `key()` function -- which is again an XSLT 2.0 - only feature.

So, you'll have something like:

```
key('xx', concat($TN, $vChar), $vDoc)
```

**Summary**:

1. Use the **[`string-to-codepoints()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-to-codepoints)** and **[`codepoints-to-string()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-codepoints-to-string)** functions for char-by-char processing.
2. Use the 3-rd argument of the **[`key()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#keys)** function to specify context different from the current.

Comment: So how exactly is that done, "saving the original document context into a variable"?

Comment: @Maestro13: Like this: `<xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="/"/>` and this variable definition can be global (child of `xsl:stylesheet`)

Comment: @Maestro13: Was my answer (including that to your comment) useful? Do you still have problems?

Comment: I devised another solution for my problem (savingthe list of option values into a variable, using analyze-string, and then passing the list to a named template, together with another variable containing the formats). But I will definitley try your suggestion whenever I feel the need for a three parm key function call.

Comment: As a test, I used the third argument for the key function as suggested and that works perfectly. Just kept the analyze-string part instead of replacing by your suggested codepoints back and forth, because in my opinion using analyze-string is much clearer.

Comment: @Maestro13: I respectfully disagree. `xsl:analyze-string` is more complex and appropriate for complex processing. My solution simly makes a sequence of characters from the string, then processes that sequence in a very convenient way, just using `xsl:for-each`. Finally, the result (in this case each individual character) is converted back to a string and used. This is: 1. more efficient (follows from the simplicity). 2. Much more easy to understand, remember and use in other situations. 3. Very general, so that it can be remembered and used as a design pattern. 4. Can be executed in parallel.